# How Can Cypress Wait For React Loading State To Change From True to False?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

**Application:**
My React application gathers information from the server to populate the page. Whilst it is doing this, there is a spinner to show the page is loading.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => getCandidate(), []);

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingInformation />;
  } else if (candidateInformation) {
```

And in the `getCandidate()` function, it'll run `setLoading(false)` upon success in the `try` block.

**Cypress Testing:**

My assumption would be that cypress sees this loading spinner, but still runs the start of the tests. This means, for example, the code below would look at the loading spinner, and throw an error:

```
cy.get("[datacy='firstName']").find("input").invoke('val')
```

Whilst I can introduce `cy.wait(5000)`, I feel this is bad practise.

How can I wait for the `state` to change from `true` to `false` before starting the code? Do I need to add a `datacy` attribute to the loading spinner (`<LoadingInformation />`), and then run a conditional? How could I do this logic globally? As it'll be on every test.

Comment: I guess there is a bigger question here, which is "How do I wait for asynchronous tasks in React to complete before running the next cypress task?"

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability

Comment: I haven't worked with react/cypress yet, but you could [intercept the api call](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Waiting) and add the tests after the call, not a 100% sure how it works with state updates etc, but i think it is worth a look

Comment: Why was this viewed to be a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess there is a bigger question here, which is "How do I wait for asynchronous tasks in React to complete before running the next cypress task?"

You're thinking too deep about your app and cypress together. Just think about it at the UI level and what Cypress can see on the page.

If you're just waiting for the candidate information to display, you can use something like `.should('be.visible')` to validate it's there. Cypress will automatically wait for the condition to pass before continuing or until it times out.

```js
// Assuming [datacy='firstName'] is a candidate information element
// Wait until this element is visible before continuing.
cy.get("[datacy='firstName']")
  .should('be.visible')
  .find("input")
  .invoke('val')
```

As @jonrsharpe posted, https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability. Retry-ability is a core concept of cypress, it's what cypress uses to wait on things.